# Should I pass a list of objects or an object to a domain object method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am developing a registration portal for a gym.  When a user registers; a list of sports are recommended based on their age; sex; fitness level etc.  Here is the tables in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID int, name varchar(100), dateofbirth datetime, Gender char(1), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE Sport (ID int, description varchar(30), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE PersonCanPlaySport (Person ID int references Person(ID), SportID int references Sport(ID), PRIMARY KEY (SportID, PersonID))
```

The tables show what sports a person can participate in. Now see the class below:

```
public class Person
{
   public List<Sport> Sports;

   public Person()
   {
     Sports = new List<Sport>();
   }

   public void AddSports(List<Sports> allSports)
   {
      Sports.Clear();
      ((List<Sport>)Sports).AddRange(allSports
      .Where(sport => sport.CanPlay(this)));
   }

}
```

This works very well.  However, in this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361040/can-two-objects-have-multiple-types-of-relationships (under question comments); a user critics the design but does not really explain why.  What is "wrong" with the design? Should I be passing single Sport objects to Person.AddSports similar to how James does it in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103693/how-to-model-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-code/1103862?noredirect=1#comment81696466_1103862?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will simply go from top to bottom without ordering by *priority*.

`Person` is not supposed to be a base class (at least now) then it should be marked as `sealed`.

`Sports` is a public field. There is not any level of *protection*. Caller might do anything with it: set it to `null`, clear the content. Add/remove items in an uncontrolled way (is, for example, `null` a valid item?) The very first thing to do is to make it a read-only property:

```
public List<Sport> Sports { get; }
```

You can assign an instance in your ctor (as you're doing now) or directly where it's declared:

```
public List<Sport> Sports { get; } = new List<Sport>();
```

The second *problem* is the type. You're exposing `List<T>` which is, at best, an implementation detail. Which operations the caller is allowed to do? Add/remove items? Clear the collection? You may change its type to `IEnumerable<Sport>` like this:

```
private readonly List<Sport> _sports = new List<Sport>();
public IEnumerable<Sport> Sports => _sports;
```

However we're just postponing the problem to the future. I'd introduce a `SportCollection` class which exposes *exactly* what you need (and to begin with it might be as little as `IEnumerable<Sport>`).

```
public SportCollection Sports { get; } = new SportCollection();
```

We fixed the declaration, we fixed the type but we still need to fix the name. It does not communicate almost anything. It's the list of sports that this person *may* play but its name is saying nothing: you have to read the code to understand how it's populated.

```
public SportCollection LikeableSports { get; } = new SportCollection();
```

I'm sure someone else can suggest a much better name but I hope you understood the point.

`AddSports()` method again does not say what it's actually doing. It's not adding *generic* sports but only sports this person may play/like. Change the name to reflect its behavior.

`allSports` parameters is `List<Sport>` but you if you change it to `IEnumerable<Sport>` you code compiles. Do it, always pick the less restrictive requirement for your parameters (what if the list comes from a DB? Do you want to materialize the whole thing in memory because `AddSports()` wants a list?)

You're clearing the list before adding the new items. It's not what I expect from a method named `Add*()`. Change the logic or change the name to reflect it.

You do not need to cast `Sports` to `List<Sport>`, just drop it.

Again a word about naming: I read `sport.CanPlay(this)` as *"Can Sport play Person?"* and it sounds weird. If this responsibility is in the `Sport` class then it should be at least named `CanBePlayedBy()`.

`Sport` has the responsibility to check if it can be played/liked by `Person`. It's debatable if this responsibility should be in `Sport`, in `Person` or much better (IMO) in a separate class. I'd go with a separate class because:

- I can switch algorithm in any moment, even from configuration and at run-time without changing anything else.
- It makes testing much easier.
- It keeps responsibilities separate and clear.
- If you add more *rules* to determine a *match* (proximity of the structure to play that sport and public transportation to/from that place, for example) you will have a single clear place where these knowledge has to be managed (unless you want to pollute your `Sport` class with references to `StructureCollection` and `PublicTransportationTripPlanner`, of course...)

Do not ignore this suggestion, it's the last one but I think *this is more important than most of the other considerations in my post*: you can live with a non `sealed` class but putting responsibilities in the wrong place will make you code a nightmare to maintain. Micro design is easy to change (with better knowledge of the domain and of the language) but wrong architectural decisions are much much MUCH more expensive to deal with (on the long term).

Comment: Thanks.  I agree with all your comments except the creation of a junction class.  Why create a junction class? It is criticised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204027/do-i-always-need-to-create-separate-class-for-manytomany-relation-in-hibernate It would make Person and Sport Anemic.  +1 for the very comprehensive answer.

Comment: It's not a _junction_ class (which, BTW is a completely different thing...link you posted is about mapping DB tables 1:1 with classes which is obviously a no-no if you're working with an ORM). It's about _responsibilities_. Where the logic to decide if a person is a good match with a sport relies? On the person? On the sport itself? From a domain point of view I'd say it's a responsibility of your _personal trainer_ (a 3rd party then, not the person and not the sport).

Comment: There is no concept of a Personal Trainer in the domain. The properties of the person e.g. age; sex etc are used to recommend sports. Therefore all the information required is in the Person class. Do you still think I need a PersonSport class? Thanks again.

Comment: No, you're mixing DB schema with domain model design. They're different things and (of course according to technical limitations and architectural considerations) should be modeled separately and independently. You do NOT need a `PersonSport` class because you're not modeling a relation between `Person` and `Sport` (and even if you did, as you already know, you should not have this in your domain classes because it's a detail hidden by your ORM). In domain model you design according to _real world_ description of the domain.

Comment: Is it the person who pick the list of sports? Is it the sport itself to say if it's compatible with a specified person? Is another separate entity who does this (for example...the service you're writing?) I'd go with the 3rd option, let's call it `PersonInterestsAggregator` (just for example...) It's a different responsibility and it's NOT a database table, it contains only LOGIC. If tomorrow you will start to consider also the proximity (and connectivity) of structures to play a given sport then it's the only place where that knowledge will reside.

Comment: You won't (obviously) add `List<Structure>` and `TripPlanner`to `Sport` and (maybe less obviously) you won't add more and more parameters to `Sport.CanBePlayedBy()` method.

Comment: I think this is more important than most of the other considerations in my post (you may live with a non `sealed` class but putting responsibilities in the wrong place will make you code a nightmare to maintain). Micro design is easy to change (with better knowledge of the domain and of the language) but wrong architectural decisions are much much MUCH more expensive to deal with (on the long term).

Comment: I can understand why you would want to create another class if PersonSport (or PersonalTrainer) contained independant attributes and methods that used those attributes.  For example, if I had a Student class and Course class and each student was given a grade for a course then I would have a class called: StudentCourse that perhaps had a method called: CalculateGrade.  However, I do not understand why you would want to add another class in my OP scenario.  I will have to put some more thought into it.

Comment: Do not reason about **data** but about **logic**. `PersonInterestInSportCalculator` does not have data but logic (the rule to determine if a given sport is suitable for a specified person). It's not a database object (even if rules MAY come from DB). It's only about **RESPONSIBILITIES** (if you like buzzwords you may want to read about _single responsibility principle_).

Comment: Is there a Gang of Four design pattern you can refer me to for this?

Comment: It's a _principle_ (see [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), not a pattern to implement. That said do NOT blindly apply principles (as _pattern_, it is just a buzzword and a pattern applied outside its context is just wrong as any other solution). Let me explain: for an extremely simple domain model you may well put more responsibilities inside the same class (to avoid an _anemic domain model_). Only you can judge where the threshold is for you specific scenario and at **this point in time** (yes, it may change).

Comment: Of course it also depends on technical limitations (for example if your ORM does not generate `partial` classes then you will likely have _stupid entities_ and all the logic in separate classes - which BTW may expose extension methods...) My rule of thumb is, usually, to start with a relatively simple design (unless it's a toy/tiny project) without overthinking architecture but also without trying to make it simpler at any cost ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) is a  good starting point to embrace and I need a good reason to do not to, not vice-versa).

Comment: Is it fair to say that if a class has a collection as a property, then another class should always be responsible for determining what should be contained in the collection? Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't generalize that much. It's really something that you should consider case by case.

Comment: Can I ask what is the point of creating SportCollection? What problem is postponed until the future by not creating it? I can see the advantage of using IEnumerable as described here: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/10/strengthening-your-domain-encapsulated-collections/.  However, what is the benefit of creating a class called SportsCollection.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link, which talks about the SportCollection idea? If you could post code to show what SportCollection looks like then that would help.

Comment: `SportCollection` can start simply implementing `IEnumerable<Sport>`. Think about this: you're exposing a list which need to be populated. If responsibility is in `Sport` (as you are doing in your code which is, IMO, better than in `Person`) then `Person` has to expose its backingstore `List<Sport>` collection as another `internal` property/method. This hypothetical `Add()`(and its friend `Clear()` are however tied to the collection itself (`SportCollection`) much more than the container (the same collection might be reused elsewhere). That's why a separate class for that.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there a link somewhere that talks about this - preferably in a DDD context? By the way; I have created a class called PersonalTrainer as per your suggestion above (if that has any bearing on this).

Comment: Hmmmm I don't remember any article exactly about this topic, probably it's just the habit to give a name to any entity you draw when describing the domain: talking about DDD when sketching the ontology you need to give a name to your sets and I usually keep those names as class names.

Comment: Could you post some code? I think I know what the class would look like - just want to be sure.  Maybe just properties and method names?

Comment: Just what required by `IEnumerable<Sport>` (the two `GetEnumerator()` methods) and `IReadOnlyCollection<Sport>` (`Count` and indexer). Of course you also need to add something (unless you accept `IEnumerable<Sport>` as ctor argument) then probably also an `internal void AddRange(IEnumerable<Sport> items)` method. I'd start with something that easy, I think.

Comment: So the collection class will have a ireadonlylist and two methods?

Comment: Yes, it's a possibility but don't blindly implement what I'm saying (even if it's just an exercise). Try with and without collection and see which code seems more "clean", that will be the solution for your specific case.

Comment: One more thing - if I am going to use NHibernate to map to this class then I guess I cannot use the Sealed keyword. Unless I am misunderstanding your answer? This is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364547/net-orms-need-virtual-and-cant-deal-with-sealed

Comment: Yes, with NHibernate you _should_ use non `sealed` classes and `virtual`properties. Well, you are not obligated (you can use interfaces) but you'll need to write more code (and I honestly dislike to have an interface 1:1 with a sealed class, required only because of technical limitations). You may also drop them all (`sealed` and non `virtual`) but in that case NHibernate isn't able to use proxies (and they're a central feature to have decent performance). That said I don't use NHibernate from many years then something might be changed

Comment: Are you able to have a look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533699/code-mapping-to-a-private-field.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm sorry I can't help with NHibernate, it's really a long time I do not use it!

Comment: With regards to your comment: "Person is not supposed to be a base class (at least now) then it should be marked as sealed.".  Say I am not planning to inherit from person today but may tomorrow (or next week or next year), then is it good practice to seal it today? Is there any documentation to support this?

Comment: From an intuitive point of view: removing `sealed` does not make class _contract_ stricter then it's not a breaking change (you can do it when you will need it and you won't need to change existing code). Vice-versa is obviously not true. Just Google, I remember Eric Lippert wrote one/some nice blog articles about it.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you mean this one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/22/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed/.  Are immutable objects e.g. DDD Value Objects all supposed to be sealed?

Comment: Not sure if it's that one but surely possible! Value objects? There are good chances they are sealed but generalization is evil. I'm sure there are cases where they should NOT be sealed. Personally I mark EVERYTHING `sealed` and I remove it if/when needed. When I'm writing code someone else will use then I have to spend more time thinking when my code need to be extended...longer job and usually involves much more design thinking. That's why it's easier to write `sealed`classes.

Comment: If you expose your implementation details then anyone is free to use it. If you will need to change it then you will break existing code. A change in the implementation will break outside code? That's bad design! Then you need to spend much more time thinking about your interface (which now has a bigger surface area because it includes `protected` members) and how it may be misused. BTW sometimes you do not have this option (for example because an ORM need to subclass your data objects) then take it _cum grano salis_.

Comment: Thanks.  One more thing - I guess you have a separate data model to your domain model and that is why you can seal the classes?

Comment: With an ORM you need two set of classes (data and domain) only in a very complex scenario. It will add complexity (and reduce the value of the ORM itself...) then it's something to do ONLY if you can't do anything else. In practice? Never or rarely. Not every ORM needs non sealed classes, if your ORM does then well just live with it and leave them unsealed. There are more important aspects you can spend design time!

Comment: Say you were developing a Domain Layer only of an app - say it was a test.  Would you concern yourself with the ORM details e.g. add a zero arguments constructor and make the class inheritable - just for your ORM.

Comment: @w0051977 honestly there aren't "fixed answers". Imagine you have a `Person` class mapped to DB. Let's imagine that your ORM forces you to have public setters (!), non sealed class and a default ctor. Worse, that all your collections (for example `Person.Hobbies` must implement a given interface (say `IDbSet<T>`). This is a bad thing for your domain model because you will have many compromises. You then rename it to `PersonDto` (for example) and it is now inside your DAL. You introduce a new `Person` class without any trade off imposed by an ORM...

Comment: ...OK, you still have (many?) trade offs imposed by the language and the tools/libraries/frameworks you're using but let's ignore them. Now you have to "map" properties and content bidirectionally between `Person` and `PersonDto`. Ok, let's introduce an OOM. Let's assume there isn't too much friction and everything is smooth. Now you have (probably) to add support (in your domain model) for a repository, query objects, transactions and what else. That's a HUGE work and a big performance penalty. Is it repaid? In some circumstances it is well repaid but more often than not you just added...

Comment: ...complexity. To make it short? I'm happy to accept compromises imposed by the ORM if what I get is more than what I pay. In my experiences there are only _few_ circumstances where benefits don't overcome drawbacks (and, again just in my experience, it had never been the case in a small/medium application). Note that if an ORM is too restrictive then you're free to use something else (and no, do not abstract the ORM using a repository pattern unless it's absolutely unavoidable)

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you are of the view that there should be no persistence model? One more question (I promise): if you have a persistence model and a domain model then I guess it means the domain model can be sealed and I can have private properties?

Comment: There _is_ a persistance model. You just don't write it...anyway, yes in MOST small/medium applications I think you do not need to write it (of course unless you're working with a _database first_ approach and a legacy DB). If you have both then yes, let's fully work with what the language we're using can offer (no doubt language itself and/or other libraries will impose another limit). Think about services where the data transfer objects are probably coarse to minimize number of calls over the wire. (I think that you meant private _setters_)

Comment: I have asked a follow on question to this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186207/testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer-3.  Could you take a look?