# Testing the process of assigning offers to a customer 3

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Following on from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186148/testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer-2).  I have made a very small change (changes are commented on in the code).  Please see the test code below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTest
{
    private IList<IProduct> _products;
    private Concor _concor;
    private Chestnut _chestnut;

    private IOfferCalculator _offerCalculator;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUp()
    {
        _offerCalculator = new OfferCalculator();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _concor = new Concor();
        _chestnut = new Chestnut();
        _products = new List<IProduct>();
        _products.Add(_concor);
        _products.Add(_chestnut);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_receive_a_concor()
    {
        var expectedConcor = new List<IProduct>();
        expectedConcor.Add(_concor);
        var gender = "F";
        var expenditure = 1500M;
        var customer = new Customer(gender,expenditure);
        //Act
        var eligibleProducts = customer.GetEligibleOffers(_offerCalculator, _products);
        //refactored this code to loop through the eligible products
        foreach (IProduct eligibleProduct in eligibleProducts)
        {
            customer.AddOffer(eligibleProduct);
        }       
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(customer._assignedProducts, expectedConcor);
    }
}
```

and the supporting code below:

```
public class Concor : IProduct
    {
        private const decimal _expenditure =100;
        private const string _gender = "F";

        public bool IsEligible(string gender, decimal expenditure)
        {
            if (expenditure > _expenditure && gender == _gender)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Chestnut : IProduct
    {
        private const decimal _expenditure = 100;
        private const string _gender = "M";

        public bool IsEligible(string gender, decimal expenditure)
        {
            if (expenditure > _expenditure && gender == _gender)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IProduct
    {
        bool IsEligible(string gender, decimal expenditure);
    }

    public interface IOfferCalculator
    {
        IEnumerable<IProduct> CalculateEligibility(string gender, decimal expenditure, IList<IProduct> products);
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Gender { get; protected set; }
        public decimal Expenditure { get; protected set; }
        public IList<IProduct> _assignedProducts = new List<IProduct>();

        public Customer(string gender, decimal expenditure)
        {
            Gender = gender;
            Expenditure = expenditure;
        }

        public IEnumerable<IProduct> GetEligibleOffers(IOfferCalculator offerCalculator, IList<IProduct> products)
        {
            return offerCalculator.CalculateEligibility(Gender, Expenditure, products);
        }

        //Refactored this method to only accept one product
        public void AddOffer(IProduct eligibleProduct)
        {
            _assignedProducts.Add(eligibleProduct);
        }
    }

    public class OfferCalculator : IOfferCalculator
    {
        public IEnumerable<IProduct> CalculateEligibility(string gender, decimal expenditure, IList<IProduct> products)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                if (product.IsEligible(gender,expenditure))
                {
                    yield return product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have simply made the following changes:

1. Renamed `AssignOffer` to `AddOffer`
2. `AddOffer` accepts a single product rather than a list of products
3. The test method loops through the products instead of the Customer class

The reason I have made this change is to be more consistent with what I am seeing online like [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Supplier.cs) and [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Order.cs).  Notice that single entities are added to the collections in both links.

I cannot find any examples similar to the way I approached it in my [other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186148/testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer-2).

I would be grateful for comments on, which approach to use as I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment.

**Update**

A change is needed to `Chestnut.IsEligible().`  The first line of the if statement needs to change to: `if (expenditure < _expenditure && gender == _gender)`.  Notice the greater than operator changed to a less than operator.

Please note that Concor is not affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any big issue, just few minor design details.

Both `Coconut` and `Chestnut` implements `IProduct` and their implementation is the same. This makes me consider two alternatives:

- In this case inheritance maybe is not the best *tool* for this job. I does not know for sure because I cannot see the *big picture* but someone strongly disagree to design a hierarchy just to add a state, without any added/changed behavior. This is not a suggestion but more a thing to consider (also according to your database design).
- Introduce an abstract base class `Product` where you put the shared implementation (Do not Repeat Yourself).

Also note that `IsEligible()` may be slightly simplified:

```
abstract class Product : IProduct
{
    public bool IsEligible(string gender, decimal expenditure)
        => expenditure > _expenditure && gender == _gender;
}
```

Now you have to choose, inheritance or not? If not then you can go one step further: make `Gender` and `Expenditure` two public properties, add a `Name` property make `Product` a concrete class and...read the product list from database. This is definitely the most flexible structure because you do not have to introduce more and more code when adding new products. I imagine this pseudo-code:

```
var customer = new Customer(...);
var offerCalculator = new BlackFridayOfferCalculator(...);

var eligibleProducts = customer.GetEligibleOffers(offerCalculator, database.Products);
```

In the other case (keeping hierarchy in place) you just need to add a `protected` ctor to `Product` to accept `gender` and `expenditure` parameters (which are also `private readonly` fields in the base class).

An important note: with this *code* approach you need to have all your entities in memory (it depends on the ORM you're using but I suppose they can't track down virtual method invocations). It means that your queries will consume a lot of memory and CPU and your super optimized fine-tuned database engine with indices won't be able to help. Think twice about this.

```
<EDIT>
```

Few quick thoughts about your edited question:

How many different products you have? If they're just FEW (and you're reasonably sure that they'll remain few in near future) then I'd keep the hierarchy (but note the paragraph about performance, probably ALL your entities will be retrieved and materialized in memory outside the DBE). If, however, you have a fair amount of products, they'll grow in future or they must be managed somehow (for example to add/remove products or to change their properties) then hard-coded solution is absolutely a no-no and you definitely should have a generic `Product` class (not abstract).

On the other side to have different `IsEligible()` expressions will quickly make your code much harder to write. You can start easily with a simple flag (expenditure greater or lower than) but for more complex scenarios I'd introduce some external business logic. If calculation is done in memory then it's easy: pick an expression evaluator like NCalc and move the condition to database (as simple text).

Note that code generation here may help you: it's fairly easy to read a configuration/list of products and to generate all the code you need (with hierarchy or not) and also producing all the relevant SQL code. Sometimes I used NCalc expressions in conjunction with its `ExpressionVisitor` to generate SQL, JavaScript, and plain English *translations* of my business logic (expressed as an NCalc expression and evaluated as such in C#). Without much more knowledge about your scenario and domain I can't suggest anything better but just give you few (there are many more options...) ideas to begin playing with.

```
</EDIT>
```

---

Now few *minor* details. You have a field `Gender`. Let's refine this concept step by step. Now you're using `==` (current culture, case sensitive) for comparison. What you probably want is to use invariant culture comparison (eventually case insensitive) or even just ordinal comparison. Use `String.Equals()` and make it explicit.

However *gender* does not need to be a string. It might be a simple `enum` with two values `Male` and `Female`.

However *gender* defines the sexual orientation of a person. It's not the sex at birth. If you stick with the *gender* then you should definitely provide much more options (Agender, Bigender, Demigender, Intergender, Non-binary, Cisgender, Transgender and so on, just to mention few). If you need to know customer's gender then you should pick a good list, read it carefully and stick to it. Do not underestimate this aspect because *gender* is an important and delicate topic.

On the same line you should note that these definitions are *fluid* and subject to change, if you're not using *sex at birth* (or *sex assigned at birth*) then you better move this list into a separate database table. Also note that what it's acceptable to present in this list may vary according to the country then logic behind this is much much more complex than you may expect. There are also privacy implications you can't ignore...are you still sure you need to know customer's gender instead of assigned sex at birth?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response.  With regards to the Product abstract class - could you have a look at my appended question (see update section).  I guess this negates the need for a Product abstract class?

Comment: It depends. How many different products you have? If they're just FEW (and you're reasonably sure that they'll remain few in near future) then I'd keep the hierarchy (but note the paragraph about performance, probably ALL your entities will be retrieved and materialized in memory outside the DBE). If, however, you have a fair amount of products, they'll grow in future or they must be managed somehow (for example to add/remove products or to change their properties) then hard-coded solution is absolutely a no-no and you definitely should have a generic Product class (not abstract)

Comment: On the other side to have different IsEligible() expressions will quickly make your code much harder to write. You can start easily with a simple flag (expenditure greater or lower than) but for more complex scenarios I'd introduce some external business logic. If calculation is done in memory then it's easy: pick an expression evaluator like NCalc and move the condition to database (as simple text).

Comment: The data model is separate to the domain model.  Therefore I believe a generic Product class is not needed.  Do you agree?

Comment: I don't know. To make it very short...it depends if the list of products is short and more or less immutable. If not then I'd introduce a generic Product class. If, however, you have a lot of logic in your domain classes (and it can't be abstracted in categories) then you can definitely avoid the generic one(s).

Comment: Notice that this is the third question I asked on this.  Please see the first question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186124/testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer.  I originally had an abstract Product class, however the answerer advised me to remove it.

Comment: May I ask what you think of an abstract base class for Entity and ValueObject as described here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/ .  I am thinking abiout adding them.

Comment: I quote: "You made Product an abstract class but this is not necessary. It does not provide any default implementation for anything so an simple interface would be enough.". If there isn't any default implementation then you do not need an ABSTRACT base class. Use it if you have some code OR if it's not abstract and the only one...

Comment: I'll take a look at that article!

Comment: I realise I have accepted, however I can still upvote.  Notice that customer._assignedProducts is a list rather than an object.  However, as it stands it will only ever contain one product (it may contain more than one in future).  Have I chosen the right data structure here?

Comment: @w0051977 yes, a list is appropriate (you're right exposing `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`) if you know that it will soon be a list. About that field I have two other concerns which I didn't note when I wrote this review: 1) it's prefixed with an underscore then I'd expect it to be a private field (but it's public) and 2) it's a public uncontrolled field, make it a property.

Comment: thanks.  I have another requirement where this time there will likely only be two products.  Would I still use a list or something like Chain of Responsibility? - last question.

Comment: Chain of Responsability or list...for what? They're two different _things_, not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @ Adriano Repetti, I would replace Customer._assignedProducts with an object (IProduct) and then use the chain of reposibility pattern to ensure that only one class handles each request.

Comment: I asked a question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190594/using-specs-when-testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer.  It focussed on testing scenarios, however t3chbot criticized my use of EligibilityCalculator claiming that it just delegates responsibility to the products.  What do you think?

Comment: Hello @w0051977! Thats's a controversial topic. In this very specific case I'd tend to agree with t3 because that class really adds nothing and just delegates to _something_ else. However...

Comment: Having a _service_ in-place lets you write specific tests (simply providing a mocked service version). Not something to underestimate. Also it's easy to have complex rules which spans over multiple products (if I bought a bicycle then I have have a special discount for helmets...) I, usually, follow your path to move it to a separate service (mostly because I _feel_ it does not belong to `Product` because it has its own separate business rules). Biggest _problem_ (and relative design decision) is IMO where that logic belongs. If it uses data from `Product`? If things start to be complex...

Comment: ...then I usually consider to introduce separate entities (data without logic) to hold this. It's a step in complexity then not something you want to do until you REALLY need it.

Comment: BTW if `Product.IsEligible()` is there _for convenience_ but you expose a service `EligibilityCalculator` then you should make those methods `internal` (they're just an implementation detail, subject to change if your logic will become more complex, don't make them part of your contract). Yes, it's a code smell but it MIGHT be an acceptable compromise.

Comment: I hope I can also add few words about SpecFlow. I don't think it's useless outside _academia_, it has its own niche and it's definitely a skill you want to learn. However it does not replace _traditional_ unit testing and it's not required to do BDD. In my (very opinionated) experience it's useful when you have to interface with testers and QA without programming knowledge. They can write _plain English_ sentences (**even before you start writing your code**) and they will server both as detailed specifications and tests. **They're documentation everyone can understand**. That's invaluable.

Comment: The way you wrote them now is, a pain for programmers (you) because for each _sentence_ they need to write a single test. If you're writing everything by your own then it's just more verbose without any added benefit. QA will write _random_ sentences and it's your duty to translate them to code. Programmers' time is more expensive. What you should really try to do is to _compose_ those tests, that's where SpecFlow shows its potentials. Classic example is the calculator: _"When I type 1 and then I type 2 then I select addition then I expect 3"_. You do not want to write one test for each...

Comment: ...input. What you want are functions you can compose (`[Given("When I type (.*)"]` and so on). You are now providing a _framework_ that testers can use to build SpecFlow tests. Do they forget to check for division by zero? They won't call you to add such test, they just write it because they already have the tools they need.

Comment: Last reminder: don't replace your unit testing with SpecFlow, complement it (if you have to, it's not a mandatory thing if your scenario does not involve someone else to write and/or share these _specifications_).

Comment: Thanks.  If you would like to answer my other question here then please do: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190594/using-specs-when-testing-the-process-of-assigning-offers-to-a-customer.  I would be specifically interested to see what you think of the quality of the Specflow scenarios and particularly this line: expectedCreditCard.Add(_availableProducts.OfType<Chestnut>().Single());.  I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment.